# Regular Expression for International Phone Numbers

Tags: regex

I am hopeless at regular expressions!

I need an expression that captures numbers formats on +441234123123

The + must remain at the beginning of the string but the numbers proceeding it must be 1-9 and of any length.

Comment: Please be aware that different languages use different formats for regexp

Comment: Please be aware that phone numbers can include 0.

Answer (score 3):

Since there's no `+0` phones:

```
^\+[1-9][0-9]*$
```

if you want exactly 1-9 (no zeros at all, which is strange for phone numbers), then:

```
^\+[1-9]+$
```

And (thanks to comments below) - if you want to capture your phone (i.e. string can contain something else), then:

```
\b(\+[1-9]+)\b
```

Comment: I think this is probably an appropriate answer, though it differs from the OP's spec, which says "numbers … must be 1-9 and of any length".  (I think this is a problem on the OP's part, not this answer's.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor got your point, edited - thank you

Comment: Don't use ^ and $, because OP didn't specify that the phone number is the only item on a line.

Comment: @NRitH edited too :) Thanks you. Shame on me

Comment: If your going to match anywhere in the string, I would take off the \b word boundry requirement, otherwise it won't match things like `(+12345678_)`

Answer (score 1):

`\+[1-9]+`

This is really quite a simple one. I suggest you look at one of the many tutorials online (like [this](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm)).

Also have a look at [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com), for help with creating them.

Comment: This is the exact answer to what the OP stated. And its unclear if the only content of the string are + and \d.

Answer (score 0):

A regex that matches your description is pretty simple: `\+[0-9]*`.

Comment: I suppose I should add that I'm assuming the `1-9` in the question is a typo, since a phone number can definitely contain `0`.